# How to disable Basic Authentication on the client

Tags: http, basic-authentication

I have a site that uses basic authentication to prevent widespread public access to a particular folder.  The material in the folder is not "secret" - it's just preferred not to be available to the whole world.

Some of our users - but only a small percentage - can no longer access material in this folder - they just get an immediate 404 error, no request for the username/password.  The same thing happens if we have them specify the username/password with the url (ie. https://user:passwrd@mysite.com/privatefolder/page.html).  Things work as always for everyone else.

I know basic auth is unsafe... we have 'real' security for things that matter.

I suspect that basic auth has been disabled on the client - either at the machine or browser level - but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that, so that I can then start to solve the problem.  Or, is this something that can be filtered at a higher level (ie. location firewall)?

It would be a headache to attach individual usernames and passwords to this folder - most users will never remember individual credentials and will complain (rightfully) about the hassle - so would like to replicate the problem to explore solutions.

How might organizations disable basic-auth at the client level for their users?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: this is up to the web server configuration

Comment: I should have been more specific in my question - I am asking how basic-auth might be disabled on the client side.  I have edited the question.

Comment: you can't disable it on the client side.

Comment: Are you sure the affected users are getting 404 and not 401? 404 means "not found", whereas 401 means "not authorized". You should have them open their browser's built-in HTTP debugger to see what the actual requests/responses look like. Maybe the server is redirecting them to another url that doesn't exist?

Comment: I stand corrected - one user reported "404" but when asked to send a screenshot, it was 401.4 which of course makes sense.  I am pretty sure this is something happening on the client side, despite the differing comment - I maintain the server, and everything works fine for most users... and the users having a problem all work at widespread locations but for the same agency.